# Android animation in listview : create translation from bottom to top like Google Plus app

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

**[UPDATE]**

I am just found this great article :

http://kylewbanks.com/blog/Implementing-Google-Plus-Style-ListView-Animations-on-Android

=========

I am trying to reproduce the animation which is appears in Google plus app when user scroll in bottom. Each time, the new item appears with a translation from bottom to top.

I believed that it was a 3D animation but it is not this type of animation.

=> How can i produce the Google Plus animation (translation ?) ?

Here is my actual code which works and produce a 3D animation :

**In getView method :**

```
Animation anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(90.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, false, rowView);
anim.setDuration(500l);
rowView.startAnimation(anim);
```

**Rotate3dAnimation class :**

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

/**
 * An animation that rotates the view on the Y axis between two specified angles.
 * This animation also adds a translation on the Z axis (depth) to improve the effect.
 */
public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
    private final float mFromDegrees;
    private final float mToDegrees;
    private final float mDepthZ;
    private final View mView;
    private final boolean mReverse;
    private Camera mCamera;

    /**
     * Creates a new 3D rotation on the Y axis. The rotation is defined by its
     * start angle and its end angle. Both angles are in degrees. The rotation
     * is performed around a center point on the 2D space, definied by a pair
     * of X and Y coordinates, called centerX and centerY. When the animation
     * starts, a translation on the Z axis (depth) is performed. The length
     * of the translation can be specified, as well as whether the translation
     * should be reversed in time.
     *
     * @param fromDegrees the start angle of the 3D rotation
     * @param toDegrees the end angle of the 3D rotation
     * @param centerX the X center of the 3D rotation
     * @param centerY the Y center of the 3D rotation
     * @param reverse true if the translation should be reversed, false otherwise
     */
    public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float depthZ, boolean reverse, View view) {
        mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
        mToDegrees = toDegrees;
        mDepthZ = depthZ;
        mReverse = reverse;
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
        float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

        final float centerX = mView.getWidth()/2;
        final float centerY = mView.getHeight()/2;
        final Camera camera = mCamera;

        final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

        camera.save();
        if (mReverse) {
            camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
        } else {
            camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
        }
        camera.rotateX(degrees);
        camera.getMatrix(matrix);
        camera.restore();

        matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This push_up_in.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" 
          android:duration="500"/>
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" 
          android:duration="500" />
    </set>
```

Now For Implementing that:

```
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity,  R.anim.push_up_in);
 yourlistitemView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Perfect ! That's it ! I will add a slow duration now. Thanks